# Changing different images by the press of a button

Tags: android

I have an imageView and a Button and  trying to change different images in an image view by the click of a button. I know how to set an image in an image view that is by

```
 img.setBackground(getBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);
```

but in my specific case i have 4 images and i want them to switch when the button is pressed. How can i do it?

Comment: post your code please so that someone can edit it.Writing the whole code may keep them away from posting.

Comment: You want to each click image has been change..

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3491125/1697047

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example with an integer array and a global variabel:

```
  private int[] drawables = {R.id.image1,R.id.image2,R.id.image3,R.id.image4};
  private int clicks = 0;

  yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v){

        if(clicks<drawables.length-1){
          clicks++;

        }
          else{

              clicks=0;
         }
         img.setImageResource(drawables[clicks]);
       }

    });
```

Should just give a possibility, check the code if works correct. I can´t check it for now, but it should give You a simple idea.

Comment: A better way : 
img.setBackground(drawables[clicks++%drawables.length]);

Comment: But it is crashing after the images end

Comment: what You mean with "after the images end" ?

Comment: sorry, got it, I know what You mean. You have to sub 1 from drawables.length, because drawables.length gives You the number of it´s content, but counting inside array starts with 0

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
int counter=0;

public void onClick(View v){

    imageView.setImageResource(image_array[counter]);

   if(counter==3){
      counter=-1;
   }
   counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this try the following steps one by one in your code
1) keep your images in an array like

```
int imagearray[]=`{R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2....};`
```

2) declare a variable `int count=0;`

3) inside the onclick of your button try the following

```
  count++;
  imageView.setImageResource(imagearray[count]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1_id);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Perform action on click   
                    img.setBackground(getBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);

                }
            });

final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2_id);
            button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Perform action on click   

             img.setBackground(getBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2);

                }
            });

final Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3_id);
                button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Perform action on click   

          img.setBackground(getBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image3);

                    }
                });
```

Comment: OP wants to click only one button not for multiple buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have 4 images in arraylist as,

```
a=new ArrayList<String>();

a.add("R.drawable.image1");
a.add("R.drawable.image2");
a.add("R.drawable.image3");
a.add("R.drawable.image4");

Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1_id);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Perform action on click   
             Collections.shuffle(a);
             img.setBackground(getBackgroundResource(a.get(0));

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int clickCounter = 0;
private int[] drawables = {
    R.id.image1,
    R.id.image2,
    R.id.image3,
    R.id.image4
};

public void myOnClick(View v) {
    clickCounter++;
    switch (clickCounter) {
        case 1:
            img.setImageResource(drawables[clickcounter]);
            break;
        case 2:
            img.setImageResource(drawables[clickcounter]);
            break;
        case n:
            break;
    }
}
```